# Hadoop: Sorting by first two keys numerically?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am looking for hadoop (using Streaming and Python) to sort the outputs of the Mapper by the first two keys;

My mapper prints as follows `print '%s\t%s\t%s' & (num1, num2, value)`

I want my reducers to receive this data sorted by `num1` and then `num2`, so that these outputs:

```
2   1   C
1   2   A
10  3   D
1   10  B
```

are delivered to reducers like so (assuming we have 3 reducers):

```
1   2   A
1   10  B
-----------
2   1   C
------------
10  3   D
```

I have tried to use the `mapred.text.key.partitioner.options` option setting it to `-k1n,1 -k2n,2` but this doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas?

I basically want Hadoop to perform this `unix` sorting: `sort -k1n,1 -k2n,2`

The version of Hadoop I am using is 0.20.2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not answer your question, but here is a solution: if you simply concatenate `num1` and `num2` in your mapper output, the default sort will do the trick.
Just be careful with the printed format: you need to control the number of zero before non-zero numbers (e.g. `0002` preceeds `0010`, but `2` follows `10`).